# Virtual box shared folder visible in Ubuntu Guest, files not shared

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-folders

Trying to make a local non-networked shared folder from a Windows 11 host to a Ubuntu 22.04.2 guest in VirtualBox. Currently, changes on the guest or host machine are not reflected in the other's shared folder, but I am able to view the shared folder in the guest.

I automount the shared folder with virtualbox on creation, have guest additions installed (as verified by lsmod), and added myself to the vboxsf:x:999 group. What else can I check?

Comment: From the Linux guest, in Linux Explorer,  SMB://192.168.x.x/folder where the IP address is the address of the Windows box. This works - I use it. To go the other way install Samba on the Linux guest.

Comment: "shared folder" is ambiguous when talking about virtualbox.  It has it's own internal driver and mechanism to share files which are exposed by installing the guest extensions.  There are also samba (SMB) shared folders from Linux to Host that can be used.  The internal stuff is probably faster and I have not had problems with it other than problems you have already solved (the vboxsf group addition).  On the flip side, you could use samba to connect to an actual windows network share on the host.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I am trying to use the internal driver shared folder, not a network based shared folder. Updated post to be a bit more clear.